# Campo Minado, bombas aleatórias

Tags: c#

Boa tarde estou com certo problema usando o método `random` para tentar aparecer somente 10 bombas no meu campo minado, só que ele aparece sem limites. alguém sabe aonde estou errando?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Camp
{
    class Program
    {

        static int[,] matriz = new int[10, 10];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PreencherMatriz();

        }

        static void Bomba()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int linhaRand = 0;
            int colunaRand = 0;
            //bool minValue = false;
            bool maxValue = false;
            int bomba = 0;
            do
            {
            bomba ++;
            linhaRand = rand.Next(1, matriz.GetLength(0) - 1);
            colunaRand  = rand.Next(1, matriz.GetLength(1) - 1);
            if ( matriz[linhaRand, colunaRand] == '9')
            {
                maxValue = true;
            }
            }while(!maxValue && bomba <= 1);


            matriz[linhaRand, colunaRand] =0;
            LerMatriz();

            Bomba();


        }

        static void LerMatriz()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", matriz[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }

        static void PreencherMatriz()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if(j == 0 || j == matriz.GetLength(1) - 1)
                    {
                        matriz[i, j] = 5;
                    }
                    else if(i == 0 || i == matriz.GetLength(0) - 1)
                    {
                        matriz[i, j] = 5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matriz[i, j] = 9; 
                    }
                    Console.Write("{0} ", matriz[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Bomba();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No final da função `Bomba` você está chamando ela novamente, o que faz com que o código execute sem parar.

Comment: Mas seu retiro ali, ele nao funciona, oque posso fazer ? pode me orientar pfv

Comment: Como foi seu professor que passou vc deveria estudar mais um pouco e verificar o que vc esta fazendo com seu código debugando linha a linha principalmente no seu me método Bomba();  dentro do seu 'if ( matriz[linhaRand, colunaRand] == 9)' vc deveria trocar o valor _9_ por seu 10.. fica a dica.

Comment: Obg  pelas dicas de todos conseguir executar o codigo funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem como sua lógica funciona, mas a verdade é que o problema esta em como você quer posicionar as bombas.
A sua matriz ao passar no método `PreencherMatriz()` sai com o seguinte resultado:

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Se ele for o responsável pela quantidade de bombas inseridas então ai esta o erro, e não tem nada a ver com o `Random`.

E se o método `Bomba` é quem deveria realizar qualquer modificação nessa matriz para marcar as posições das bombas, ele não esta atribuindo valor nenhum valor dentro do seu loop que imagino que seria ali que deveria estar contando quantas bombas foram inseridas.

@edit:

```
static void Bomba()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int linhaRand = 0;
    int colunaRand = 0;
    int bomba = 0;
    do
    {
        linhaRand = rand.Next(1, matriz.GetLength(0) - 1);
        colunaRand  = rand.Next(1, matriz.GetLength(1) - 1);
        if ( matriz[linhaRand, colunaRand] == '9')
        {
            //adotando que onde é 0 é bomba
            matriz[linhaRand, colunaRand] = 0;
            bomba ++;
        }
    }while(bomba < 10);
    LerMatriz();
}
```

Comment: Professor me pediu uma coisa bem simples, 5 seria a borda 9 vazio está faltando eu introduzir 10 bombas random  sem passar da borda. 
Ao fazer isso somente parece 1 bomba. e obs as bombas tem que aparecer aleatoriamente.